# How can I tell if a file has the Windows "hidden bit" in Emacs?

Tags: windows, emacs

I use Emacs on various platforms. When I use it on Windows, I don't want files with the "hidden attribute" to show on ido-find-file, dired, etc. I can't seem to find any function in Emacs that can tell me whether a file has the hidden bit or not (file-attributes doesn't seem to, from the help page).

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for not having an answer. Here is something to lighten your day: http://xkcd.com/378/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific elisp function that will tell you whether or not a file's hidden attribute is set on Windows.  However, you can write an elisp function that invokes the Windows [`attrib`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) command and parses its output.  For example, `(shell-command-to-string "attrib c:\\foo.txt")` would return a string like `A   HR    c:\\foo.txt` (in this particular example, the file has three attributes set: archive, read-only, and hidden).  At that point, you just need to look for the `H` in the string that `attrib` returns to determine whether or not the file is hidden.

Comment: This is what I was planning to do if there wasn't an elisp function. I didn't know about the "attrib" call, however - saves me from writing some Python script to do it. Thanks.

Comment: A search through Emacs' code shows nothing for hidden files, and `file-attributes` returns the same thing whether the hidden bit is on or off.